# Custom filter in Tensorflow: has_nan

Tags: debugging, tensorflow

I need to implement a custom filter that only stops whenever a dumped tensor gets 'nan' value. The current implementation of TF has the  has_inf_or_nan which is not good for me. I require a filter to only stop on 'nan', not 'inf'. It would be even more efficient for me to filter a specific tensor by name. Can anybody give an idea where should I start from?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully follow your question. Are you trying to _debug_ your code and you want to set up a filter with `tfdbg` which stops only on `NaN`s and not `inf`?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. I was able to set the filter with the following function:

    def has_nan(datum, tensor):
    if hasattr(tensor, 'dtype'):
        if (np.issubdtype(tensor.dtype, np.float) or
            np.issubdtype(tensor.dtype, np.complex) or
            np.issubdtype(tensor.dtype, np.integer)):
            return np.any(np.isnan(tensor))
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False

Then with the following it is added the filter to the session. 
train_sess.add_tensor_filter("has_nan", has_nan)